# Update WebClip : Execution of request failed

Tags: c#, .net, google-email-settings-api

I'am new with the API ! I'am trying to build some console app to auto setting emails for my domain !
I add our domain to google app and link it with google server !
( So I'm able to receive and send mail )

I tried to do one think : Disable WebClip using this Code !

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GoogleMailSettingsService service = new GoogleMailSettingsService("mydomain.com", "your-apps");
        service.setUserCredentials("alaeddine.gallas@mydomain.com", "********");
        try
        {
            service.UpdateWebclip("alaeddine.gallas", "false");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Console output :
Execution of request failed: https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/mydomain.com/alaeddine.gallas/webclip

I tried also to retrieve labels but it throw me the same exception !

Did I miss something ? Did I have to enable something in the domain management portal ?
What I have to do to make thins code run ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to execute any other operation?

As far I know the ClientLogin authentication method was deprecated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.

Comment: No I'can't ! I tried to create a Label but it doesn't work ? do you know why ?